# What is the driver equivalent of GetNumaProcessorNodeEx?

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, numa

I am currently trying to hook up some kernel threads in a driver to specific NUMA nodes. To do so, I need to query the NUMA node of individual processors.

Unfortunately, GetNumaProcessorNodeEx is not available from a driver (it requires Windows.h). What is the driver equivalent of that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [KeQueryLogicalProcessorRelationship](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553031%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and request the RelationNumaNode.  This will get you the affinities for every NUMA node in the system.